# Finding value in database by max(ID) and save as a Variable in c#

Tags: c#, variables, save

I've a problem with my program in c# and i hope, you can help me.

My database looks like this:

http://www11.pic-upload.de/08.09.15/czq5yxrrcf24.png

and I want to save the last value of "MaxZyklus" in a variable in c#.

My query to the server is okay, when I write it like this:

```
select Kabel.maxZyklus 
from Kabel 
where Kabel.kabelTyp = 'PM-K031' 
  and ID = 20; 

select max(ID) from Kabel
```

but I don't know, how I can do it in one query, and save it in C# as a variable

Hope you can help me.

Comment: This seems more related to basic SQL than to c#.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT YourField FROM YourTable 
WHERE YourKey =(SELECT MAX(YourKey) FROM YourTable )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct query at

```
select Kabel.max Zyklus form Kabel where ID = (select max(ID) from Kabel where Kabel.kabelTyp = 'PM-K031');
```

now saving in a vatiable :) suggestions?